# Prove or disprove that if $f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

such that $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ and $f$ is continuous, then exists $x_0 \in [0,1]$ that satisfies $f(x_0) = x_0(4-x_0)$.

The intuition is clear that should be such an $x_0$. Since $g(x) = x(4-x)$ is strictly monotonic and continuous on $[0, 2- \sqrt{3}]$, hence $f$ and $g$ have to intersect at least at one point in   $[0, 2- \sqrt{3}]$. But how to formalize this assertion?

Thank you.

Comment: Let $h=g-f$.  Then $h(0)\le0$ and $h(0)>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $h(x) = f(x) - x(4-x)$. Then

- $h(0) = f(0) \ge 0$,
- $h(1) = f(1) -3 \le 1 - 3 < 0$.

What can you conclude?

Comment: If $h(0) = 0$ then $0$ is such a point and if $h(0) > 0$ then by the intermediate point theorem exists $x_0$ in $(0,1)$ such that $h(x_0) = 0$. Is this right?

Comment: @J.Doe: Yes, exactly.